# Search and replace: float arithmetic

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

For example I have many numbers like `111.222`, I want to decrease them to 0.1 (to get `111.122`), how to do that? I tried:

`:%s#\d\+\.\d\+#\=submatch(0)-0.1#`

But as a result I have `110.9`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, you need to convert the string to a Float explicitly, using [`str2float()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#str2float()):

```
:%s#\d\+\.\d\+#\=str2float(submatch(0))-0.1#
```

To explain what you're seeing without the explicit conversion, vim has two numeric types: Number (for integers) and Float (for floating point numbers.) When using a string in numeric context (for example, with an arithmetic operation such as `-`), vim will do an implicit conversion, but it only converts strings to *Number*, not Float. Trailing characters are ignored in the conversion, so it just stops at `.`, the decimal point.

The end result is that `111.222` will be converted to the Number 111.

Then, when performing an arithmetic operation between a Number and a Float, vim will first coerce the Number into a Float. So, in your case, it will get to `111.0-0.1`, finally yielding `110.9`.